# Dropwizard integration with hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate, build.gradle, dropwizard, hibernate-envers

I want to implement audit functionality to the table data. `Hibernate Envers` provides that feature.

But I couldn't add that to `dropwizard`, Have anyone done that.
Does `dropwizard-hibernate` supports this kind of auditing features?

My Gradle config

```
  'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
  'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-hibernate:' + dropwizardVersion,
  'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:' + dropwizardVersion,
  'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:' + dropwizardVersion,
  'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:' + dropwizardVersion,
  'com.hubspot.dropwizard:dropwizard-guice:0.8.0',
  'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final',
  'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final',
  'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.11.Final',
  'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:4.3.11.Final',
```

Comment: What attributes do you want to audit? I never used dropwizard-hibernate but hibernate alone. Since all the config is in the persistence.xml file, what is the issue with adding Envers?

Comment: @pandaadb My problem is, I could not integrate it with dropwizard, If I put it as a separate jar, I am able to annotate my classes for audit. I am using gradle build and I added my gradle config in the question.

Comment: I believe this would be because by docs the envers depend on registering the appropriate listeners in your persistence.xml but the hiebrnate-bundle for dropwizard does not user a persistence xml but rather uses the annotated classes?

Comment: I thimnk there are two options: 1. drop the dropwizard approach and set up hibernate via persistence.xml. Basically write your own extension for that, it's what I did. Or, overwrite the sessionfactory creation on the hibernate bundle from dropwizard to register the correct interceptors/listeners for the auditing.

Comment: You might be able to hook in your properties by adding them to the PooledDataSourceFactory. Look at: SessionFactoryFactory#buildSessionFactory. That is where your hibernate stuff happens, this is where you will want to add the properties configuring your Envers setup. It looks like, by dropwizard docs, you can set ALL those properties in  the yaml. https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.1/docs/manual/hibernate.html
have you tried that? let me know how that goes.